# program to get all the combinations of ball-box application

Tags: algorithm, combinations, number-theory

I am new to combination and permutation related algorithms. Does anybody have any thoughts on how to program to solve this classical problem? There are 3 boxes(A,B,C) and 10 balls(1,2,3,...,10), we want to put all balls into the boxes. The result should be {Box A: ball 1; Box B: ball 2,3,4; Box C: ball 5 6 7 8 9 10}, {Box A: ball 1 2; Box B: ball 3 4 5; Box C: 7 8 9 10}, .... I want to get all combinations (not the number of different combinations).
Furthermore, what if there is a constraint that each box contains at most 4 balls?

Thank you.

Comment: Didn't mean that. Just an idea or explanation is enough to help me to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the first ball in any of three boxes, so you have three variants.
 There are three variants for the second ball, three for the third and so on.

They are independent, so you have 3^10 variants, and each variant has 1:1 mapping with a number in range 0..3^10-1.

Consider number in ternary number system, so k-th ternary digit of number tells us what box (a=0,b=1,c=2) k-th ball belongs to.

Example for 3 balls:
Number 14 = 112 ternary, so first ball in C, second and third in B

For case of limited box size simple approach is recursive generation - arguments of recursion are list of available balls and current combination (list of boxes with balls and vacant places).